# Deploying database into different environments with application-specific data

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I do have a requirement in which I need to deploy my database into different environments with application-specific data on the target environment.
For an instance, we are integrating with a 3rd party services and they do have different credentials and other parameters specific to the target environment. Such as credential and endpoints and other parameters for test and prod environments.

Currently, we are using post-deploy DB scripts targetting those environments and stored them on our git repository.
I read and heard we should not commit such sensitive information in repositories due to the risk of hacking and stealing.

Can someone suggest a better way (best practices) of handling this requirement in your CI/CD pipeline?

We are using **TeamCity** and **Octopus** tools in our CI/CD process.

Appreciate your valuable advice and feedback in this regard. 
Also feel free to share the best CI/CD practices to overcome such concerns in your development process.

Thanks,
RSF

Comment: not pretending to "best practices"... the easiest based on what you have: use a separate git repository with access only for admins, or teamcity project parameters.

Comment: potentially keep data like usr/psw as a [sensitive variables](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/sensitive-variables)  per environment.

Comment: Hi @AlexM, Thanks for your feedback.
How do you read Octopus variables in your *.sql script files? Appreciate your advice.

Comment: You can deploy your dacpac with [sqlpackage.exe passing variables in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017) (/v: variable1 = value1).

Comment: Thanks @AlexM, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

I would have approached it by keeping data like usr/psw as a [sensitive variables](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/sensitive-variables) per environment in `Octopus`.

To deploy I'd use [sqlpackage.exe passing in the dacpac and the variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#command-line-syntax) (/v: variable1=value1).